# insert row/column with css table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried for a while to duplicate the jquery insert row / insert column functionality that I have working for an html table to a css table. I have searched and experimented for a solution without success.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/4kb3p7qz/2/) to to my work, I took out my attempted code because it was useless.

My code is listed below.
Thanks for any help.

**html**

```
    div class="ws-css-table" >
      <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td" id="1"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td" id="2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td" id="3"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td" id="4"></div>
    </div>
</div>     
<br/>
<button id="css-irow">CSS-Insert Row</button><button id="css-icol">CSS-Insert Column</button><br/><br/>

<br/>
<br/>
<table border="1" id="mtable">

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="container"></td>
        <td class="container"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="container">a</td>
        <td class="container">b</td>
    </tr>  

    </tbody>
</table><br/>



<button id="irow">Insert Row</button>
<button id="icol">Insert Column</button><br/><br/>



<br/>There are <span id="rowcount"></span> rows
<br/>There are <span id="colcount"></span> columns
```

**jquery**

```
$('#css-irow').click(function(){
  });
$('#css-icol').click(function(){ 
 });

////////////////////////////////////////////
$('#irow').click(function(){
$("#mtable tbody tr:last").clone().appendTo('#mtable tbody').find("td").empty();   

    var rowCount = $('#mtable tr').length;
    $("#rowcount").text(rowCount)   
    });
////////////////////////////////////////////
$('#icol').click(function(){ 
        $('#mtable tr').append($("<td class='container'>"));
        $('#mtable thead tr>td:last').html($('#col').val());
        $('#mtable tbody tr').each(function(){$(this).children('td:last').append($(''))});

     var col = $('#mtable tbody tr:first > td').length;
    $("#colcount").text(col);    
});
```

**css**

```
.ws-css-table {
    display: table;


}
.ws-css-table-tr { 
    display: table-row;     
}
.ws-css-table-td { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by a css table?? :|

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - What do you mean by "what do you mean by a css table??" ... Do not see any confusion here other than semantics

Comment: sorry if my explanation is not so clear. I was hoping the fiddle would help explain. What I mean by a css table is that the css code is acting like an html an html table.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Out of curiosity and to learn the verbiage, what words should I have used instead of "css table"? thanks

Comment: CSS table is the proper verbiage to use. It is a table you are creating with CSS as opposed to an html table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished in the following way. This uses the same method you used and clones the divs into their respective locations.

Run the code snippet below ::

```js
$('#css-irow').click(function(){
 $(".ws-css-table-tr:last").clone().appendTo('.ws-css-table');
});
$('#css-icol').click(function(){
 $(".ws-css-table-td:last").clone().appendTo('.ws-css-table-tr');
});
```

```css
.ws-css-table {
    display: table;
}
.ws-css-table-tr { 
    display: table-row;     
}
.ws-css-table-td { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ws-css-table" >
  <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>
</div>     
<br/>
<button id="css-irow">CSS-Insert Row</button><button id="css-icol">CSS-Insert Column</button><br/><br/>
```

This should help you get started.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate you help.